# What happens to previous DataContexts in Visual Tree when DataContext on same View is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I have my custom Calendar control - **Event Calendar**. I use it in a View of some case.

```
<Controls:EventCalendar Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="8"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="20,50,0,0"
                        CalendarEvents="{Binding DataContext.CalendarEvents, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Header="{Binding DataContext.DataSpis.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ViewModelBase="{Binding DataContext.ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        IsFunctionalityVisible="{Binding DataContext.IsFunctionalityVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        IsCaseLoaded="{Binding DataContext.IsLoaded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Controls:EventCalendar>
```

I detect if the case is loaded (same view, different data) via **IsCaseLoaded** Dependency Property. When this happens, I add new **DataContext** to my Calendar Control. Like this:

```
private static void LoadPCCallback(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (((EventCalendar)source).IsCaseLoaded == true)
  {
    ((EventCalendar)source).DataContext = null;
    ((EventCalendar)source).DataContext = new EventCalendarViewModel(((EventCalendar)source).Header, ((EventCalendar)source).ViewModelBase, ((EventCalendar)source).CalendarEvents);
  }
}
```

In constructor of **EventCalendarViewModel** I set some visibility for Meetings or Tasks I want to show. By default Meetings are shown and Tasks are hidden.
When I want to show Tasks, I click on Button on this Calendar Control.
And now where the behaviour starts to be *unexpected*: I load the Case, click on Tasks Button, it works - Tasks are shown, Meetings are hidden.
I reload the Case, click on Tasks Button, it works - Tasks are shown, Meetings are hidden.
But third time I reload the Case (sometimes second, sometimes fourth - really *random*), Constructor works, sets Meetings as default, but when I click on Tasks Button, it suddenly has values from previous DataContext, so it thinks Tasks are *true*, Meetings are *false*... so nothing changes and Meetings are still shown.

```
public void ShowMeetingsButtonClick()
{
  this.ShowTasks = false;
  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowTasks);
  this.ShowMeetings = true;
  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowMeetings);
}
```

Show Tasks is also like that:

```
public void ShowTasksButtonClick()
{
  this.ShowMeetings = false;
  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowMeetings);
  this.ShowTasks = true;
  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowTasks);
}
```

So one thing that comes to my mind is, somehow this View of Calendar founds previous **DataContext** in **Visual Tree** and takes old values from there. Because after constructor of new DataContext everything seems fine, but after clicking on a button it suddenly has different values.

I also thought some of my threads are changing something, but I tried to debug it and no one them (only Main Thread) are active during this.

Comment: This is a tricky one. Because there is a lot of potentials for side effects in code which is not shown here. Can you show more code? TasksViewModel, MeetingsViewModel, CalendarViewModel?

Comment: [EventCalendarViewModel](http://pastebin.com/nucFGhA1) here ... Tasks and Meetings don't have their viewmodels, Do you want also EventCalendar.xaml? To see how I bind ShowMeetingsButtonClick?

Comment: [EventCalendar.xaml](http://pastebin.com/nYzEa0kQ) ... There is a lot of code, so I dont know if you will find what you want and understand what I meant by some things

Comment: also I tried some edits (with no success) - such as adding _this.Refresh()_ and a lot of _NotifyOfPropertyChange_ stuff

Comment: empty datacontext before setting new one.. like this:  ((EventCalendar)source).DataContext = null;  ((EventCalendar)source).DataContext = new EventCalendarViewModel...

Comment: I tried it before and still the same problem... (I actually have that line in current code, so I will edit in post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I try to rebuild some stuff to simulate your behavior. And came up with this and it should be fairly close to the behavior your are heading towards.

I added an `InverseToBooleanConverter` which show the the visibilty in the opposite way of the bool (false  = Visible). This helps with the toggling stuff

I added a Converter for the GridLength (Your Height) coming from an Integer. And I took the liberty to create an Enum which represents the value of `Show` and `Hide`.
Important rule keep your ViewModels pure no Namespaces that starts with System.Windows or any view related stuff.

I somehow sorted your Properties and the PropertyNotification-Stuff. Goal is to keep it as tight and lean as possible. So for this code I only had calls to OnPropertyChanged from within the property itself.

For me the `TaskListView` is a `Control` and will have it's own `ListOfTaskViewModel` (with behavior) and it's collection of Tasks (depending on the complexity in it. This could also be an `ObservableList<TaskItemViewModel>`)
The same will apply for the `MeetingListView` with it's `MeetingListViewModel`.
Now it is important where and how to load Data. I could think about a Service which has at least 2 methods `GetTasksForCaseID` and `GetMeetingsForCaseID`which could be injected in the ViewModel or the loaded data could be passed on. I prefer to keep things independent and would use some thing like an `EventAggregator` or a `Messenger` to notify the `ViewModel` with the matching ID as payload. And keep the responsibility to the `ViewModel` to fetch the data. But this depends and since I had not enough information about your context this was out of the scope for the example. But I hope you get the idea.
This right here is the MainViewModel class

The same thing would also apply for your actual Events in the calendar and the highlight stuff. It Should be separated in a own ViewModel with own view control to keep things clean.

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Init();
        }

        public enum Calendar{
            ShowCalendarMaxLength = 145,
            HideCalenderHeight = 325,

        }

        private MeetingsListViewModel _listOfMeetingsViewModel;
        public MeetingsListViewModel ListOfMeetingsViewModel {
            get { return _listOfMeetingsViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if (_listOfMeetingsViewModel != value)
                {
                    _listOfMeetingsViewModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ListOfMeetings");
                }
            }

        }

        public TaskListViewModel _listOfTasksViewModel;
        public TaskListViewModel ListOfTasksViewModel { 
            get{return _listOfTasksViewModel;}
            set {
                if (_listOfTasksViewModel != value)
                {
                    _listOfTasksViewModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ListOfTasks");
                }
            }
        }

        private Calendar _calendarEventListBoxHeight;
        public Calendar CalendarEventListBoxHeight
         {
             get { return _calendarEventListBoxHeight; }
             set
             {
                 if (_calendarEventListBoxHeight != value)
                 {
                     _calendarEventListBoxHeight = value;
                     OnPropertyChanged("CalendarEventListBoxHeight");
                 }
             }

         }

        private bool _showCalendar;
        public bool ShowCalendar
        {
            get { return _showCalendar; }
            set {
                if (_showCalendar != value)
                {
                    _showCalendar = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ShowCalendar");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _showTasks;
        public bool ShowTasks
        {
            get { return _showTasks; }
            set
            {
                if (_showTasks != value)
                {
                    _showTasks = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ShowTasks");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _showMeetings;
        public bool ShowMeetings
        {
            get { return _showMeetings; }
            set
            {
                if (_showMeetings != value)
                {
                    _showMeetings = value; OnPropertyChanged("ShowMeetings");
                }
            }
        }

        public void ShowCalendarAction()
        {
            ShowCalendar = true;
            CalendarEventListBoxHeight = Calendar.ShowCalendarMaxLength;
        }

        public void HideCalendarAction()
        {
            ShowCalendar = false;
            CalendarEventListBoxHeight = Calendar.HideCalenderHeight;
        }

        public void ShowMeetingsAction()
        {
            ShowTasks = false;
            ShowMeetings = true;
        }

        public void ShowTasksAction() {
            ShowMeetings = false;
            ShowTasks = true;
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            ShowCalendar = true;
            CalendarEventListBoxHeight = Calendar.ShowCalendarMaxLength;
            ShowMeetings = true;
            ShowTasks = false;
            ListOfMeetingsViewModel = new MeetingsListViewModel();
            ListOfTasksViewModel = new TaskListViewModel();
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

And this is the XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Views"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"   
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
        <conv:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseVisibilityConverter"/>
        <conv:GridViewLengthConverter x:Key="LengthConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Calendar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowCalendar, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
                      >

            </Calendar>

        <Button Margin="0,12,0,0"  
                                   FontSize="15"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Content="Show Calendar" 
                                   Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowCalendar,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource InverseVisibilityConverter}}"  
                               ToolTip="ShowCalendar">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ShowCalendarAction" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </Button>
        <Button Margin="0,32,0,0" 
                                   FontSize="15"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowCalendar,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"  
                                   Content="Hide Calendar" 
                                   ToolTip="HideCalendarButtonClick">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="HideCalendarAction" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </Button>
            <Button Margin="0,5,0,0"   
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   FontSize="15" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowMeetings,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource InverseVisibilityConverter}}"    
                                   Content="Show Meetings" 
                                   ToolTip="ShowMeetingsButtonClick">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ShowMeetingsAction" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </Button>
        <Button Margin="20,5,0,0" 
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   FontSize="15"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowTasks,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource InverseVisibilityConverter}}"  
                                   Content="Show Tasks;" 
                                   ToolTip="ShowTasksButtonClick">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ShowTasksAction" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </Button>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              MaxHeight="{Binding Path=CalendarEventListBoxHeight, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter }}"
              Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowMeetings, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
              >
                <views:MeetingsListView DataContext="{Binding Path=ListOfMeetingsViewModel,Mode=TwoWay}">

                </views:MeetingsListView>
            </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              MaxHeight="{Binding Path=CalendarEventListBoxHeight, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter }}"
              Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowTaks,Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}}"
              >
                        <views:TaskListView DataContext="{Binding Path=ListOfTasksViewModel,Mode=TwoWay}" />
              </Grid>

    </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For the sake of completeness the two converters:

InverseBooleanToVisibiltyConverter

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(Visibility))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

            if (!(bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

GridViewLengthConverter

```
 class GridViewLengthConverter:IValueConverter{


        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double val = (int)value;
            GridLength gridLength = new GridLength(val);

            return gridLength;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            GridLength val = (GridLength)value;

            return val.Value;
        }
    }
```

I guess you could remove some code by optimizing your toggle behavior with less booleans =)...

**//Edit:** I strongly believe that the issue is outside the code you have shown. Especially the loading and exchange part or what was describe in your comment as "a lot more complex functionality" in the case ViewMode. Nevertheless since you have already an IsCaseLoaded-Property in place. I assume you are doing some async data fetching here. Async/await could also be tricky with MVVM. Especially when mixing UI-related operations with background operations. Attached you find some helpful links how to deal with async code and MVVM. This series shows approaches for async-bindable-notification-properties, async IComannd implementation and async services.

Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Commands
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx

Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Services
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683795.aspx

Hope that helps...

Comment: Hi, I am going to try it now. It sounds really reasonably. I came to work today and first thing which came to our mind was to try change Converter and maybe use Enum, like you wrote up here... I will give it a try. Thanks for help and useful answer

Comment: Let me know if your problem still exists after the changes and we can elaborate further...

Comment: Yes, problem still exists. I found out that after a few times (mostly 3) of loading the Case (adding new ViewModel to DataContext) Calendar is somehow still connected to previous ViewModel. Even if constructor is properly working and in UI it is reloaded (I see default data). But after I click on a Button, it is working with previous ViewModel. How is possible, that it can find the previous one? It shouldnt have any connection now. It should be removed by garbage collector in that time, or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you share some more details on how you load a case and refresh, etc. So I do think the issue is before all that ...

Comment: [EventCalendar](http://pastebin.com/GKD3ZYK1) this is my View, I wait until `IsCaseLoaded` is changed, then in `LoadPCCallback` I assign new DataContext.
And `IsCaseLoaded` is binded in another ViewModel (CaseViewModel). There when the case is loaded it is _true_. This seems to be working, because every time it is loaded `LoadPCCallback` is called.

Comment: So click on an Event then your fire LoadCase after LoadCase returns then you set the datacontext in the clb? Or is there a CaseView with a CaseViewModel which loads Events, Meetings and Tasks and then "navigates" to EventsCalendar? If so... please share some details about the other CaseView with ViewModel and "your navigation" =)

Comment: There is CaseView nad CaseViewModel which loads Events, Meetings and then navigates to EventsCalendar...
There will be a lot of code, so I hope you can understand:  
[CaseView](http://pastebin.com/HHvcHyy1) is simple, but [CaseViewModel](http://pastebin.com/fchZ3sE9) is quite robust... also there is [ListBoxCalendarEvent](http://pastebin.com/nH0JrGUm) which is ViewModel for the Events. Up in the post is how I use EventCalendar in Case.xaml

Comment: Thanks for your help and big effort. I really appreciate it. I have async loading. I tried to debug my threads, but in the moment when my error appears there are no threads active (except of main thread). I will check your links, hopefully I will find something useful.

Comment: I finally managed to return to this problem and solve this. Problem was indeed in using Async and Await... Thanks for your help!